# LeetCode Problem same Tree, why does my code fail when input contains "Null"?

Tags: python, algorithm, data-structures, binary-tree

I am looking at the LeetCode problem "[100. Same Tree](https://leetcode.com/problems/same-tree/)":

> Given the roots of two binary trees p and q, write a function to check if they are the same or not.
>
> Two binary trees are considered the same if they are structurally identical, and the nodes have the same value.

My code passes some test cases and fails others.

My specific problem is with the test case `[1,2] and [1,null,2]`. Python uses `None` not `null`. When I use my local code editor (visual studio code) it produces the expected output. I know I could implement this in other ways but I don't understand why this solution won't work on LeetCode.

Here is my code:

```py
class Solution:
    def isSameTree(self, p: Optional[TreeNode], q: Optional[TreeNode]) -> bool:
        answer1 = []
        answer2 = []
        self.helperFunction(p, q, answer1, answer2)
        
        for i in range(len(answer1)):
            if answer1[i] != answer2[i]:
                return False   
        return True
    
    
    def helperFunction(self, p, q, answer1, answer2):
        if p != None and q != None:
            self.helperFunction(p.left, q.left, answer1, answer2)
            answer1.append(p.val)
            answer2.append(q.val)
            self.helperFunction(p.right, q.right, answer1, answer2)
```

Comment: See [mcve] . . .

Comment: Can you include the rest of the code required to run this, and also the code that you're using to set up and verify that the test that fails but you claim works correctly does so along with its expected output?

Comment: A cursory reading of `helperFunction` indicates that it completely ignores when one tree being compared does exist but the other does not. As the simplest example you could test that I think will be wrong: does your code indicate that an empty tree and a tree with a single node (any value) are the same or different?

Comment: Does leetcode actually present you with a python `None` or the string `"null"`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code assumes that both trees have the same shape. If however one tree has a child where the other doesn't, your code never visits that child, and this will give false positives when the rest of the tree is the same. The mere presence of such a child (that does not exist in the other tree) would be enough indication to abort the process and return False.

As to the algorithm itself. It is a pity that you do this:

```
    answer1.append(p.val)
    answer2.append(q.val)
```

...when you could actually *compare* these two values immediately (instead of doing this at the very end). Why not check `p.val == q.val` and if that is not true, stop looking any further? On the other hand, if they are equal, there is no reason to append those values to lists either. It just means "so far so good", and you can continue...

Concluding:

- Return True when at both sides there is no node (`None`)
- Return False when on one side you have a node that is not there on the other side
- Return False when the values of corresponding nodes are different
- Return True if and only when the recursion also returns True for both children.

Implemented:

```
class Solution:
    def isSameTree(self, p: Optional[TreeNode], q: Optional[TreeNode]) -> bool:
        return bool(not p and not q     or
                    p and q and p.val == q.val and self.isSameTree(p.left, q.left) 
                                               and self.isSameTree(p.right, q.right))
```

Comment: I guess no need to cast to bool explicitly here

Comment: If the caller will deal well with `None`, that is true, @funnydman, but as the signature of the function has a `bool` type hint, it is more consistent to avoid that it would return `None` (which would happen when `p` is a `TreeNode` and `q` is `None`).

Answer (score 2):

Let's look at your "answer1" and "answer2" variables for the following input:

input:

> [1,2]
> [1,null,2]

output:

> answer1 = answer2 = [1]

as you can see, your program incorrectly stops comparing the nodes of the two trees once one of the values "p" or "q" is null in your helperFunction. This is due to the following line of code:

```
if p != None and q != None:
```

A simple fix for your bug could be this:

```
def isSameTree(self, p: Optional[TreeNode], q: Optional[TreeNode]) -> bool:
    answer1 = []
    answer2 = []
    self.helperFunction(p, q, answer1, answer2) # changed
    
    return answer1 == answer2


def helperFunction(self, p, q, answer1, answer2):
    if p != None and q != None:
        self.helperFunction(p.left, q.left, answer1, answer2)
        self.helperFunction(p.right, q.right, answer1, answer2)

    if p is None:
        answer1.append(None)
    else:
        answer1.append(p.val)
        
    if q is None:
        answer2.append(None)
    else:
        answer2.append(q.val)
```

Comment: I've tried the solution on leetcode and received an AC. Therefore yes it does suffice. The values of answer1 and answer2 are [1, None] and [None, 1] respectively

Comment: I realised what you mean tho, and you are right. I will update the post for a more accurate solution.

Comment: Ok, still not sure about your original, but the new version looks correct. Although I find the normal way (like trincot's) easier to understand.

Comment: I agree too, Trincot's solution is more space efficient and easier to understand. I assumed the OP has already seen that solution on Leetcode's solution editorial on this question. I was focusing on why the OP's solution is not working rather than give a different solution

Comment: Some improvements: answer1.append(p.val if p else None), answer2.append(q.val if q else None) and no need to explicitly check p!= None, just if p and q.